# How to add a value to an existing Array in Firestore which already has this exact value, without "overwriting" it?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my quiz app the player types in his first answer as an `Integer`, which creates an `array` in Firestore like this:

```
Map<String, Object> answer = new HashMap<>();
answer.put("answers", Arrays.asList(answerPlayer1Int));

answerRef.document("Round 1").collection(uidPlayer1).document(uidPlayer1)
       .set(answer).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

              }
        });
```

In the next fragment, he types in his second answer for the second question, and I want this value to be added to the previously created array. Currently, I use the code below, which works when the first answer and the second answer are not identical but when the first answer equals the second, the second answer does not update the array list as I would like to.

I know what the reason for this is, but I want to know now, is it even possible to just add any kind of value to an existing array in Firestore?

Here is the code of the second answer:

```
answerRef.document("Round 1").collection(uidPlayer1).document(uidPlayer1)
        .update("answers", FieldValue.arrayUnion(answer2Player1Int)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

              }
           });
```

This is the output that I currently have when the player uses the same answer for each question:

[image]

And this is how I want the output to be:

[image]

Any help is again much appreciated!

Comment: get the data and add your values to local map and set it again

Comment: @JamaldinSabirjanov This work work yes. But I would use an different approach. Since I am using a ViewModel to sent the answer to the next fragments I can actually use that value without getting it from the database, this saves me some reads. Thank you for your approach, this helped me

Comment: @Kaiser Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have multiple even duplicate elements in your array, then you should read the document, get the array, update it and write it back.

You can also solve this by using the `arrayUnion` operator but this time it ensures that each unique value exists only once in your array. There is no way you can add a duplicate value when using the `arrayUnion`.

Please also be aware, that according to the official documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

> If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code,with **SetOptions.merge()** I think this will work,

```
Map<String, Object> answer = new HashMap<>();
            answer.put("answers", Arrays.asList(answerPlayer1Int));
            answerRef.document("Round 1").collection(uidPlayer1).document(uidPlayer1)
                    .set(answer,SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                }
            });
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: This unfortunately did not work, but thank you for your help. I am using now another approach similar to the one JamaldinSabirjanov suggested